# Insert thousands entities in a reasonnable time into BigTable

Tags: google-app-engine, insert, entities, gql, bigtable

I'm having some issues when I try to insert the 36k french cities into BigTable. I'm parsing a CSV file and putting every row into the datastore using this piece of code:

```
import csv
from databaseModel import *
from google.appengine.ext.db import GqlQuery

def add_cities():
spamReader = csv.reader(open('datas/cities_utf8.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t', quotechar='|')
mylist = []
for i in spamReader:
    region = GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM Region WHERE code=:1", i[2].decode("utf-8"))
    mylist.append(InseeCity(region=region.get(), name=i[11].decode("utf-8"), name_f=strip_accents(i[11].decode("utf-8")).lower()))
db.put(mylist)
```

It's taking around 5 minutes (!!!) to do it with the local dev server, even 10 when deleting them with db.delete() function.
When I try it online calling a test.py page containing add_cities(), the 30s timeout is reached.
I'm coming from the MySQL world and I think it's a real shame not to add 36k entities in less than a second. I can be wrong in the way to do it, so I'm refering to you:

- Why is it so slow ?
- Is there any way to do it in a reasonnable time ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you try with the [bulk uploader](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html)?

Comment: Because I'll need to do the same thing with online parsed datas, which won't be in a data file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it's the datastore, not Bigtable. The datastore uses bigtable, but it adds a lot more on top of that.

The main reason this is going so slowly is that you're doing a query (on the 'Region' kind) for every record you add. This is inevitably going to slow things down substantially. There's two things you can do to speed things up:

- Use the `code` of a `Region` as its `key_name`, allowing you to do a faster datastore get instead of a query. In fact, since you only need the region's key for the reference property, you needn't fetch the region at all in that case.
- Cache the region list in memory, or skip storing it in the datastore at all. By its nature, I'm guessing regions is both a small list and infrequently changing, so there may be no need to store it in the datastore in the first place.

In addition, you should use the [mapreduce framework](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) when loading large amounts of data to avoid timeouts. It has built-in support for reading CSVs from blobstore blobs, too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html).  If you want your dataset to process quickly, have your upload handler create a task for each subset of 500 using an offset value.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW we process large CSV's into datastore using mapreduce, with some initial handling/ validation inside a task.  Even tasks have a limit (10 mins) at the moment, but that's probably fine for your data size.

Make sure if you're doing inserts,etc. you batch as much as possible - don't insert individual records, and same for lookups - get_by_keyname allows you to pass in an array of keys.  (I believe db put has a limit of 200 records at the moment?)

Mapreduce might be overkill for what you're doing now, but it's definitely worth wrapping your head around, it's a must-have for larger data sets.

Lastly, timing of anything on the SDK is largely pointless - think of it as a debugger more than anything else!